# Merging two datasets by all possible ids in r

Tags: r, merge

I have two dataframes below:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = c(11,22,33,44,55),
                  score = c(20,22,33,22,11))

df2 <- data.frame(id1 = c(11,22,NA,NA,8),
                  id2 = c(98,9,33,NA,24),
                  id3 = c(NA,NA,66,44,88),
                  id4 = c(NA,NA,NA,16,17))

> df1
  id score
1  11    20
2  22    22
3  33    33
4  44    22
5  55    11
> df2
  id1 id2 id3 id4
1   11  98  NA  NA
2   22   9  NA  NA
3  NA   33  66  NA
4  NA  NA   44  16
5   8  24   88  17
```

I need to merge the two datasets by `id` from `df1` and four ids from `df2`. I also would like to keep any unmatched `id` s from the `df1`. How can I achieve the desired output as below at once?

```
df.merged <- data.frame(id = c(11,22,33,44,55),
                        score = c(20,22,33,22,11),
                        id1 = c(11,22,NA,NA, NA),
                        id2 = c(98,9,33,NA,NA),
                        id3 = c(NA,NA,66,44,NA),
                        id4 = c(NA,NA,NA,16,NA))

> df.merged
  id score id1 id2 id3 id4
1  11    20   11  98  NA  NA
2  22    22   22   9  NA  NA
3  33    33  NA   33  66  NA
4  44    22  NA  NA   44  16
5  55    11  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

Comment: Is there guaranteed to be at most one match in each row of `df2`?

Comment: yes, one variable is supposed to match for max.

Comment: But id `44` occurs twice in `df2`. Is this an error?

Comment: sorry, yes, corrected to 88.

Answer (score 0):

You can paste together all the id's from `df2`, creating a regex pattern, then see where each pattern matches with rows of `df1`. I'd imagine that there is a simpler way to do this.

For each row `rowwise()`, paste all id's with "|" (regex or operator) in between. Then, remove extra `NA`'s with `str_remove_all("NA\\||\\|NA")`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df2_ids <- df2 %>%
  rowwise() %>% #for each row
  mutate(ids = across() %>% paste(collapse = "|") %>% str_remove_all("NA\\||\\|NA")) %>% 
  pull(ids)

df2_ids 
#> [1] "1|98|1|98" "2|9|2|9" "3|66|3|66" "4|16|4|16" "8|24|44|17|8|24|44|17"
```

Then, for each pattern, get which row of `df1` matches it. If no match the length of the `which(...)` will be `0`, and we save a `NA`.

```
df2$id <- df1$id[map_dbl(df2_ids, ~ which(grepl(.x, df1$id)) %>% {ifelse(length(.) >0,  ., NA)})]
```

Now, we have a suitable joining key, and can do a simple `left_join` (that keeps all rows of `df1`):

```
left_join(df1, df2, by = 'id')
```

This fails with a more complex case of `df2`, one where a row refers to multiple `df1` rows. Below is a more general approach.

```
index <- map(df2_ids, ~ which(grepl(.x, df1$id)) %>% {`if`(length(.) >0,  ., NA)})

df2 <- df2 %>%
  uncount(map_dbl(index, length)) %>%
  mutate(id = df1$id[reduce(index, c)])

left_join(df1, df2)
```

Comment: thanks, I changed the id values since 1,2,3,4,5 could cause non matching patterns. can you run your solution for this updated id s please?

Answer (score 0):

You can "semi-pivot" `df2`, so that there's one `id` column containing all ids while retaining columns `id1` - `id4`, then join by `id`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2_semi_pivot <- df2 %>% 
  mutate(across(id1:id4, .names = "{col}_pivot")) %>% 
  pivot_longer(ends_with("pivot"), names_to = NULL, values_to = "id")

left_join(df1, df2_semi_pivot)
```

```
  id score id1 id2 id3 id4
1 11    20  11  98  NA  NA
2 22    22  22   9  NA  NA
3 33    33  NA  33  66  NA
4 44    22  NA  NA  44  16
5 55    11  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i <- rowSums(array(match(unlist(df2), df1$id, 0L), dim(df2)))
i[duplicated(i) | !i] <- nrow(df2) + 1L
cbind(df1, rbind(df2, NA)[i,])
#>   id score id1 id2 id3 id4
#> 1 11    20  11  98  NA  NA
#> 2 22    22  22   9  NA  NA
#> 3 33    33  NA  33  66  NA
#> 4 44    22  NA  NA  44  16
#> 6 55    11  NA  NA  NA  NA
```